# var jQuery = jQuery.noConflict(); not work in IE7 and IE8

Tags: jquery

my code is

```
var jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function() {
var $filterType = $('#filterOptions li.active a').attr('class');
var $holder = $('ul.ourHolder');
var $data = $holder.clone();
  $('#filterOptions li a').click(function(e) {
        $('#filterOptions li').removeClass('active');
        var $filterType = $(this).attr('class');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        if ($filterType == 'all') {
            var $filteredData = $data.find('li');
        } 
        else {
            var $filteredData = $data.find('li[data-type=' + $filterType + ']');

        }
        $holder.quicksand($filteredData, {
            duration: 800,
            easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

when i comment ( //var jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();) noConflict then this code is work but
if not commented this then its not work with ie7 and also ie8

i use also $jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An idiom I regularly use is: place the code that uses jQuery in a function with a single argument `$`, and call that function with the jQuery object, like so:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $filterType = $('#filterOptions li.active a').attr('class');
        var $holder = $('ul.ourHolder');
        var $data = $holder.clone();
        $('#filterOptions li a').click(function(e) {
            $('#filterOptions li').removeClass('active');
            var $filterType = $(this).attr('class');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            if ($filterType == 'all') {
                var $filteredData = $data.find('li');
            } 
            else {
                var $filteredData = $data.find('li[data-type=' + $filterType + ']');

            }
            $holder.quicksand($filteredData, {
                duration: 800,
                easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 3):

if you use

```
var jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
```

You need to replace every `$('...')` with `jQuery('....')`

Answer (score -1):

if $ not work TRY:

```
  var $ = (jQuery);

  $(document).ready(function(){
    active_function();
  }); // ready
```

Comment: Can you explain how this fixes the original problem?